# Python datetime consistenly evaluates to one of the 2 values, but never the same one value

Tags: python, datetime

I'm running this line of code in the python console

`hours = ((datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=5, minutes=0)) - datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds()/3600`

Which I would expect to have the same answer every time I run it, but then hours is always set to either `-5.000000003055556` or `-5.000000003333334`

this is really confusing to me because it's the exact same line of code that I'm executing, I would expect it to always be the same number.

[image]

Comment: `utcnow` returns wall clock time.  Remember that your computer is doing many things besides running your process.  Your thread could have been interrupted by a network packet, or a mouse movement, or a disk interrupt, or a timer interrupt, or one of a hundred different things.  Those things take variable amounts of time.

Comment: @TimRoberts Why is it always one of the 2 values, and not a range of values

Comment: Do the math.  Multiply those values by 3600 to undo the division you did.  You get 18000.000011 and 18000.000012.  That's 11 or 12 microseconds.  `utcnow`, like all the `datetime` functions, tracks integer microseconds.  There are no integers between 11 and 12.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the cause is while evaluating datetime.utcnow() twice. Probably because you have a non-constant delay between this two operations.

I have evaluated this expression:

```
(datetime.utcnow() - datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds()
```

and saw different values as a result.

try doing this:

```
now = datetime.utcnow()
hours = ((now - timedelta(hours=5, minutes=0)) - now).total_seconds()/3600
```

Comment: And this delay is always going to be the exact same amount?

Comment: If you store a single operation result in a variable (as in now = datetime.utcnow()), and then reuse this variable, there will be no delay, because there will be no second operation, just a single one.

Comment: I'm wondering why the delay is consistently one of 2 values

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing execution time, which naturally varies since other processes are sharing the processor. You can reproduce the problem like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def f():
    now0 = datetime.utcnow()
    d = timedelta(0)
    now1 = datetime.utcnow()
    return (now0 - d - now1).total_seconds()

for _ in range(5):
    print(f())
```

Example output:

```
-5e-06
-2e-06
-1e-06
-2e-06
-1e-06
```

You could evaluate `utcnow()` first:

```
>>> now = datetime.utcnow()
>>> now - timedelta(0) - now
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

But why? `now - now == timedelta(0)`. You could skip the middleman and just do `timedelta(0)`, or in your case:

```
>>> timedelta(hours=-5).total_seconds()/3600
-5.0
```

Comment: `But why? now - now == timedelta(0). You could skip the middleman and just do timedelta(0), or in your case:` - Well this is just a toy example of a bigger piece of code